# Facebook PHP sdk error. Cannot get public profile

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I downloaded the facebook php-sdk and I updated it with my app id and app secret. Then I used ftp to upload it to my server. **It is a windows server.**

But when I run the `example.php` file, in the example folder, it always shows not connected. Even when I clicked on "Login with Facebook" button. But it returned a url like this:

```
http://freelankan.cu.cc/examples/example.php?code=AQATeuQKc2tmSHuy6SHyej......
```

I want to integrate my native login system with facebook's login. Is this happening because of a problem with my server or a problem in code?

**Code:**

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '8530403454382687',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}



if($user) {
    echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'Logout</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you fill this in your facebook app settings? > Website with Facebook Login

Comment: yes @chathula. i idi but it still doesnt work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happend because web hosting provider did not allow to communicate with facebook.
i think some provider does this. (most of free web hosting providers)
when i got a paid hosting. this error did not happend again.
hope this will help full.